# Interactions in linear mixed model in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, interaction

I have calculated a linear mixed model in R. My outcome variable is called VPA and is a continuous variable. For simplicity, let's say I have two categorical variables as fixed effects - group (with 2 categories) and stimulus (with 4 categories).
IF I do it like this, then the result shows that group is nonsignificant but all stimulus categories are.
I now want to know, if the groups significantly differ for each stimulus category and I understand that to achieve this, I need to include an interaction term between group and stimulus. When I do this, then the effect of group on VPA suddenly becomes significant for all stimuli categories.
This doesn't make sense to me, because without the interaction term, group did not have a significant effect on VPA.
Can somebody help me make sense of this. Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand interactions in regression? When you add an interaction effect, the main effect of a predictor becomes the effect at the reference category of the other predictor.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Sofia. This is a FAQ that has been asked in very many ways.  Please see [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interaction+significant+not).  You won't have to read the thousands of posts it finds -- a few ought to do the job.